# Using COPY INTO with a CSV file containing a Timestamp column

Tags: monetdb

I'm trying to import a CSV file using COPY INTO syntax. I have the below table

```
test(id int, name varchar(50), expi TIMESTAMP)
```

Here is an extract of my CSV file:

```
id,name,expi
1,toto,2013-01-14T23:12:34
```

I did not succeed in providing the format for the timestamp column. What should I use to replace the ??? in the command below?

```
COPY 10 OFFSET 1 RECORDS INTO test FROM '/tmp/file.csv'(id,name,???) ON CLIENT DELIMITERS ',','\r\n','"';
```

I tried `(id, name, expi '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')` to follow the example found in the [documentation](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/ServerAdministration/LoadingBulkData/CSVBulkLoads) on CSV Bulk Upload but I got the following error message:

```
COPY INTO: 'str_to_timestamp' missing for type timestamp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for asking. We've fixed this some time ago, but forgot to push the changeset to the MonetDB Mercurial repository. Thanks to your question, we noticed this oversight.  So, the `'str_to_timestamp' missing` error is fixed here: https://dev.monetdb.org/hg/MonetDB?cmd=changeset;node=7fb446b3c98c.  It'll be included in the next bugfix release.

However, I needed to make some changes to your above queries.

1. you also need to add `WITH TIME ZONE` into CREATE TABLE statement, because `strftime` (the underlying library function) gives us the time in UTC, and a (SQL) `TIMESTAMP` is local time.
2. the OFFSET should be 2

So, the following query works on Linux (note the '\n'):

```sql
create table test(id int, name varchar(50), expi TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);
COPY 10 OFFSET 2 RECORDS INTO test FROM '/tmp/file.csv'(id,name,expi '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') ON CLIENT DELIMITERS ',','\n','"';
```